# TypeError: 'Data argument can't be an iterator...'

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, logistic-regression, transpose

Im trying to use the zip function to bring the column names together and the np.transpose function to bring together the coefficients of the log_model I created.

My code:

```
# Create LogisticRegression model object
log_model = LogisticRegression()

# Fit our data into that object
log_model.fit(X,Y)

# Check your accuracy
log_model.score(X,Y)
```

This code worked just fine as I was able to check the accuracy of my model. 
However, the following code is where I get my error.

Erroneous code:

```
coeff_df = DataFrame(zip(X.columns,np.transpose(log_model.coef_)))
```

Error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-a4e0ad234518> in <module>()
      1 # Use zip to bring the column names and the np.transpose function to bring together the coefficients from the model
----> 2 coeff_df = DataFrame(zip(X.columns,np.transpose(log_model.coef_)))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    387                 mgr = self._init_dict({}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    388         elif isinstance(data, collections.Iterator):
--> 389             raise TypeError("data argument can't be an iterator")
    390         else:
    391             try:

TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator
```

What am I doing wrong? Sorry, newbie here. Im following a Udemy data visualization with Python tutorial. My lecturer is using Python 2 but I've been able to manage with Python 3, just making and researching the conversions to ensure my code still works.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do? Why are you wrapping the zip in a DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For binary classification, only one linear model is used. In the case of multi-label classification, there will be one linear model for each class. Assuming your X is a `pd.DataFrame`, you can proceed as follows:

```
output = pd.DataFrame(my_model.coef_, columns=X.columns)
```

Rows represent linear models for different classes, columns represent coefficients.